# Api creation with Instagram for doing instagram login in magento

Tags: php, magento, instagram

I am doing instagram login in my magento project. I have refferred the following link http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/login-with-instagram-php.html for doing it.. But the core they have done in core php. I am struggling to do the same in magento.

Can anyone tell me a good solution for doing instagram login in magento.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspired from this excellent free magento module: http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/.

Then you might need to check the Instagram API to see what kinds of data it needs (API key, OAUTH_URI, request token, oauth signature method etc.).

I've extended and adapted this module for Yahoo and Tumblr login.